# Transfer characteristics of circuits involving op amp with diodes

Tags: operational-amplifier, diodes, voltage-clipping

How should I approach such questions?[image: Question figure]

Comment: Use a simulation tool to get the general feel then make some approximations of the diodes and do some math.

Comment: There are two separate cases to consider. If \$ V_i \$ is positive the Op-amp output is negative and D2 conducts. If \$ V_i \$ is negative D1 conducts.  What are your thoughts?

Comment: You should approach the question by first looking at the diodes. Diodes can be on or off. What will the amplifier output voltage be to make one or the other diode not conduct? Will they ever both be non-conducting? Simplify the circuit if any diode is not conducting by removing it and any components in series with it. Now what will the input have to be to get that output voltage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself for each case (\$V_i\$ positive and \$V_i\$ negative), what the output has to do to satisfy the fundamental (idealized) property of such an op-amp circuit, which is that the input terminals are held at the same voltage.